# Numerical integration of 2-d Gaussian Distribution in MATLAB

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, matlab

I am looking for a really fast way to integrate numerically the 2-dimensional gaussian density with identity covariance matrix $\Sigma=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and some fixed and known mean value $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^2$ over the region of the plane described in polar coordinates by
$$
\{(r,\phi)\colon r\in[0,+\infty), \phi\in[\phi_1,\phi_2]\},
$$
(where $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are known),
which is the "angle" between two half-lines starting from the origin.
I need to evaluate these integrals for different values of $\phi_1,\phi_2$ (different pairs of half-lines) $n(n-1)/2$ times.

I failed to get the closed-form expression for this integral, so
i am now using MATLAB function "quad2d". For $n=100$ it takes about 1 minute. And i need to compute it for $n\approx 10^4$.

Any ideas?

Thanks alot!

Comment: I've not tested either of these functions, but other built in MATLAB integration functions for 2D include [dblquad](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/dblquad.html) and [integral2](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html).

Comment: Hi, Daryl. I believe dblquad and integral2 use the same Simpson's rule as in quad2d.

Comment: So to clarify, for my sake, you are trying to evaluate $$\iint_R e^{-(x-\mu)^T\Sigma(x-\mu)}\, dA$$, with $R$ and $\Sigma$ as defined in your question?